# checking whether variable is dictionary in python - use 'is' or ==

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

Summary: I have a variable called `'parent'` that is a dictionary in python. I want to check if it is a `dict` object. However, using `"type(parent) is dict"` gives me `'False'`.

NOTE: I have the following library loaded in my python script:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

Why is this happening? I suspected at first it is because this variable `'parent'` is created using the `json` library's `'loads'` method.

```
parent = json.loads(self.request.body)
```

However, even when I create parent like so,

```
parent = {}
```

I get the the same results as observed below:

```
        print type(parent)
          >> <type 'dict'>
        print type(parent) is dict
          >> False
        print type({}) is type(parent)
          >> True
        print type(parent) == dict
          >> False
        print type({}) == type(parent)
          >> True
```

What's going on here? Is this a python version issue? Or does this have to do with the fact I've loaded google's app engine library? When I execute the following commands in a normal terminal, with no libraries loaded (Python 2.7.5), I get the following results, which are what I expect:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2013, 21:33:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
>>> parent = {}
>>> print type(parent)
<type 'dict'>
>>> print type(parent) is dict
True
>>> print type({}) is dict
True
>>> print type({}) is type(parent)
True
>>> print type({}) == type(parent)
True
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Comment: I expect that GAE is using some sort of non-`dict` under the hood in order to optimize code behavior.

Comment: Did you name a variable `dict`?

Comment: Try `print dict` and show us what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's most likely happening is that GAE is using some subclass of `dict` behind the scenes.

The idiomatic way to check whether an object is an instance of a type in python is the [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) built-in function:

```
>>> parent = {}
>>> isinstance(parent, dict)
True
```

... which works for instances of the type itself, and of subclasses.

Comment: Judging by the tests with `type({})`, I would be surprised if this is the cause.